metra AZ-INGM1 interface for 2012 colorado - orange wire help!
So I went to AutoZone and purchase this Metra interface after buying a cheap Scosche one online that didn't work at all as it should. Now my problem is the wiring diagram shows two orange wires but says that one is labeled "IFACE ILL" and to only use that wire unless my truck harness has the other wire. Problem is neither of the orange wires had this label on them. Also I have an orange wire with a white stripe that is not mentioned in the wiring diagram at all. One solid orange wire goes to the plug for truck harness and one solid orange wire goes to the plug that goes to the green interface box. Should I hook both of these wires together and tie them into the dimmer/illumination wire of the aftermarket stereo? And then just leave the orange with white stripe wire alone?
Any help is appreciated!



